# Key Error When Trying to Merge Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes but keep getting a "Check for Duplicates Error". Here is the layout of the dataframe:

```
DF1:
City        State    Sales
San Fran    CA       $10
Col         OH       $5
Col         SC       $5

DF2:
City        State    Percent
Col         OH       3%
Col         SC       10%
New York    NY       12%
```

Desired Result:

```
DF3:
City        State    Sales    Percent
San Fran    CA       $10      0
Col         OH       $5       3%
Col         SC       $5       10
New York    NY       0        12%
```

The following code gives me the error

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['City','State'])
KeyError: 'City'
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the output of DF1.columns.values and DF2.columns.values?

Comment: df1: ['City','State','Sales'] / df2: ['City','State','Percent']

Comment: merge should be work

Comment: seems the problem is with a space in your column name. Just guessing, try the code after stripping all spaces from column names `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: @Wen-Ben: I agree, it should work.

Comment: @anky_91 - I tried to strip the columns and the result is the same.

Comment: have you checked the output of df.columns ?